# Trying to use Gecko Engine with ABCPdf and classic ASP

Tags: abcpdf

I'm trying to create dynamic PDFs using ABCPdf and I'm having no success. I copied their sample code and tried it and I receive an error:

> Unable to render HTML. No MSHTML document is available.

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Gecko engine to render the page instead of IE and can't find how.

Answer (score 1):

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11504285/1411950. This example uses the 1 rectangle for html->pdf output on each page. The rectangle is filled with raw html / html from url. It also can use Gecko engine.
If you want to make dynamic pdf, you should use raw html for its content. Note, that it should be wrapped into something like

```
    const String HtmlWrapper = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head profile='http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile'><title></title>
                    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
                    <style type='text/css'>
                    </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                {0}
                </body>
            </html>";
```

where all css goes in script tags in the header or is referenced to